# How to increase size of apps in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

Just open the image and try to see if you can read the SOAP UI Menu bar. I can't see what is on the menu bar of applications like Soap UI and Eclipse.

I tried increasing the size of menu bars but that only increases the windows explorer menu bar text size.

[image]

Comment: Hey Oliver. This doesn't appear to be something that is directly Microsoft's fault; it's largely up to the developers to choose how big they want their menu bar to be. Still, they have to conform to certain design limitations and expectations from Microsoft, so perhaps both parties are to blame.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf could you please help me to increase the font size of this. The issue is the same with Eclipse application. When I increase the menu font size it increases all mircosoft apps menu bar size like windows explorer, outlook, word, excel etc. Please help me I can't work peacefully because of this issue

Comment: Again as I'll say, I don't think it's necessarily Microsoft's doing. It's likely the programs and your monitor resolution. There might be options in Soap and Eclipse to change the sizing of those things, but I have never used Soap and it's been a few years since I coded with Eclipse, and it was on Win7 and I never had a problem with it.